# Visual Basic - RegEx - Overall Length Check regardless the number of matches

Tags: regex, vba

I have the following problem :

This is my RegEx-Pattern :

```
\d*[a-z A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 _?!()\/\\]*
```

It allows anything but numbers that stand alone like : 1 , 11 , 111 or so on.

My question : How can I set the overall Length of the input regardless of the matches ?

i tried it with several options like {1,30} before each match and i put the regex in a group with ( ) and then {1,30} but it still doesnt work.

If anyone could help me i would appreciate it :).

Allowed string:

```
Group1
Group 1
1Group
Group!?()\/
Group !()\?!
a1 a1 a1 a1
```

Not Allowed:

```
1
11
```

And so on. `{1,30}` after a match restricts the number of how many times i can input the match. What i want to know is: How can i set the maximum length of my above RegEx, like after 30 chars the input is reached regardless of the matches?

Comment: anything but numbers? Your regex should also allow `f??????????`

Comment: The question is too vague. Please provide example input and expected output.

Comment: You can't limit the "input" with RegEx, it's just a pattern matching engine. You can restrict the length of a "Match" but you need to use string manipulation _before_ you pass the string to RegEx

Comment: Allowed :

Group1 |

Group 1 |

1Group |

Group!?()\/ |

Group !()\?! |

a1 a1 a1 a1 |

Not Allowed :

1 |

11 |

and so on

{1,30} after a match restricts the number of how many times i can input the match

What i want to know is : How can i set the maximum length of my above RegEx , like after 30 chars the input is reached regardless of the matches

Comment: I can suggest [`^(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z0-9 _?!()\/\\]{1,30}`](https://regex101.com/r/hH2oV4/2). It will disallow numeric-only input and will allow matching first 1 to 30 symbols defined in the character class. Note there can be more than 30 symbols in the input, and there still will be a match since I am not using `$` at the end. If you want to restrict the input length to 30 symbols (if there is more, fail the match), add the `$` at the end. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Works almost like i want it , changed it to (?!\d*$)[a-zA-Z0-9 _?!()\/\\]{1,30} and it works perfectly ! thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, I will post it as an answer then.

Comment: Yes i will upvote it then =) thx again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to disallow a numeric string input only, you can use a negative look-ahead `(?!\d+$)` and to set a limit to the input, use a *limiting quantifier* `{1,30}`:

```
(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z0-9 _?!()\/\\]{1,30}
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hH2oV4/3)

Note that if you plan to match whole strings, you'd need anchors: `^` at the beginning will anchor the regex to the beginning of string, and `$` will anchor at the end.

```
^(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z0-9 _?!()\/\\]{1,30}$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/hH2oV4/4)

Comment: Just a note: the lookahead `(?!\s*\d+\s*$)` might be better if you plan to ignore whitespace before and after purely numeric input.